# Why main ignores the returning value of the user defined function

Tags: c, return, return-value

We all know that return statement ends the execution of the called function and returns some value to the calling function but in the case given below I didn't accept the returning value of the user-defined function via any variable or as an argument in another function like as in printf then why main printed **Hello** , according to my thinking main's execution should end after printing **5** as 0 is returned to it, I have searched it on various platforms but they just stated that main ignores the value returned (but why and how ?)

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{ 
  printf("%d\n",6);
  Array();
  printf("Hello\n");
  return 0;
}

int Array()
{
  int c=5;
  printf("%d\n",c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would `main` end when some function returns `0`? There's no problem with any value being returned.

Comment: Funny you're focusing on `Array()`, but your code ignores the return value of `printf` way more often - that's just how it works. If you don't use the return value, it is ignored.

Comment: Look out for compiler warnings too, and the code is ill formed.

Comment: `Array()` isn't known before it's called. It's a bad idea and is forbidden in modern C

Comment: There's a big difference between returning 0 **from** main, and returning 0 **to** main. The statement `return 0;` in main *will* cause main to end at that point, because you are returning 0 **from** main. But the `return 0;` in the Array function will only cause the Array function to end. It won't have any effect on main, because you are returning 0 **to** main, and main simply ignores the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `return 0;` only ends the function it belongs to. In `Array()`, it will end the execution of `Array()` function, and nothing else.
The fact that `main` ignores the return value, has nothing to do with that. But to answer the "why and how" it ignores it - You didn't tell `main` where you want to store the return value of `Array()`, so it won't store it anywhere. 
 If you said `int a = Array();`, then `main` would know to store it in variable `a`. But if you just call `Array();`, then `main` will not store the return value anywhere, therefore you could say it ignored it.